# How to enable index options

Tags: reindex, enterprise-1.14

I cant reindex manually most of index options, how can I do to enable it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the indexers are updated on save automatically.
Make sure your cronjobs are set up and configured properly, then the cron will take care of it.

See also: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/system-operations/index-schedule.html

Comment: But I would like to have manually option to do it, this is something related to enterprise version ?

Comment: Well, the indexers can be run manually, best way is via command line. Especially if you have a lot of products/options/categories you can run into concurrency issues or timeout issues of you do this via Magento Admin.

Comment: yes I know, and I like more do that in command line, but, the client wants the option to do it from admin panel, at least some of them, like search catalog. but I dont know how to enable it

Comment: Well there is no option per default to enable it. There might be a 3rd party extension somewhere but I don’t know one. Better tell your client it‘s a bad idea that can cause troubles:)

Comment: ok , thanks, the real problem is that some times new products aren't available from front end, and I need to run reindex from command line to do it. I have found that some times that is normal, but, I for us, that situation is so common and the client cant reindex from admin panel.

Comment: Maybe do you know what can cause this ?

Comment: Depends on how often the cronjobs are running I think. Every minute? Every 5 Min? Are they set up correctly?